# Spree 1.1 missing templates when inheriting from Spree::BaseController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm trying to load a customized spree page by inheriting from Spree::BaseController.

```
class PagesController < Spree::BaseController
  layout 'spree_application'

  def home
  end
end
```

But I get a whole bunch of missing template errors

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template pages/home, spree/base/home, application/home with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :coffee, :rabl]}. Searched in: *
>   "/Users/mm/StoreOnline/app/views"...

This doesn't seem right. If I have to replace all those templates I might as well just use regular rails controllers/actions/views. So my question is - is this no longer supported in Spree version 1.1+?

Comment: also tried `layout 'spree/layouts/spree_application'` but still getting all the missing template errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had the controller defined in the wrong place. Really wish Spree had better documentation on this stuff.

Anyway, move it into `app/controllers/spree/pages_controller.rb` and it worked fine.

Comment: If you think the Spree documentation is lacking, I would consider that a bug. Please file an issue on https://github.com/spree/spree-guides and we will fix it up. Thanks!